# How to get only a text from a XML file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-parsing

I tried this code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\adilipman1937067724.xml");

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xmlString);
            string t = doc.InnerText;

            textBox1.Text = t;
        }
    }
}
```

But getting error:

error: Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long. The file im trying to read is xml of chat history in my messenger with my brother. The file size is: 492kb .

Getting error exception message:

```
System.UriFormatException was unhandled
  Message=Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
       at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
       at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
       at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)
       at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\C-Sharp\AnimatedGifEditor\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 25
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in D:\C-Sharp\AnimatedGifEditor\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Could you give an example of an xml file and how you'd like to view it?

Comment: Dude you need to pass the path of the file to XmlDocument.Load, you are passing the contents of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things.

Easiest way to see whether the format of an xml document is correct is to open it in Internet Explorer. It'll tell you if there are problems.

An easy way to view the contents of an xml document, with all xml tags stripped away:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\tt.xml");
string xmlString = doc.InnerText;
```

The above method will also tell you if there problems with your xml document.

The syntax of your call looks correct, so I assume there must be a problem with your xml document. Fix that first (one problem at a time!), then have another go.

Comment: Euric im getting error: Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long. The file im trying to read is xml of chat history in my messenger with my brother. The file size is: 492kb .  how can i fix the problem ?

Comment: Show us your code. It looks as though you're treating the contents of the file as the location of the file.

Comment: I've updated my original response with my suggested fix, but it has to be peer reviewed first apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the compile error you are getting is correct, you need to close your string literal.

```
string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\tt.xml");
```

The method that you are using reads all the text from the file so of course you see the tags !!

If you just want the node values then load the xml into an XmlDocument and use the InnerText
property.

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\tt.xml");
        var str = doc.InnerText;
```

The variable str will contain the text, minus the xml tags.